# pywinauto scripts work differently in execution of file vs interactive mode

Tags: python, python-3.6, pywinauto

I'm trying to make a script for Windows application.  But the script works differently when executing the file (`python test.py`) vs. Python interactive mode.

Here is the code.

```
import pywinauto

app = pywinauto.application.Application()
app.start(r"C:\customPrograms\ControlStation.exe")
    
app.window(title_re=u'Login').Wait('visible', timeout=60, retry_interval=1)

dlg = app.Login
dlg.Edit1.TypeKeys("testSuper")
dlg.PasswordEdit.TypeKeys("test")
dlg.OK.SetFocus()
dlg.OK.click()

app.window(title_re=u'Room select').Wait('visible', timeout=60, 
retry_interval=1)

roomdlg = app.Roomselect
roomdlg.Connect.click()

app = pywinauto.Application().connect(title='tmpSuper - local')
app.testSuper.MenuBar.MenuBarClickInput('#4->#1->#0', app)
app.testSuper.People.click()
```

When I run this script as a file (`python test.py`), I've got this error:

> pywinauto.base_wrapper.ElementNotEnabled

[image]

When I run the scripts one by one in an interactive Python session, there was no error. It works fine.

[image]

What is a difference between those two ways?  What is the best way to execute automation scripts?

I'm using Python 3.6 and pywinauto 0.6.4.

Comment: The purpose of this scripts is to test existing application and it will be executed regularly as regression testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typical timing problem (you can't reproduce it step by step because there is a delay between manual steps execution). `roomdlg.Connect.click()` waits for existing "Connect" button, but not for enabled state. So the error message is meaningful.

Solution should be:

```
roomdlg.Connect.wait("enabled") # timeout is optional param, default is 5 sec.
roomdlg.Connect.click()
```

Some apps may have issues like delayed `OnClick()` handlers subscription even if button is already enabled. In this case you may need `app.wait_cpu_usage_lower()` to indicate that app process CPU usage is below threshold.

Current document about timings is here: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wait_long_operations.html (need to be extended with global timings settings though).

Comment: By the way, do you happen to know why MenuBarClickInput does not actually click?  'app.tmpSuper.MenuBar.MenuBarClickInput('#4->#1->#0', app)' this code goes and expand hidden submenu but does not actually click it.

Comment: Because this is specifically for MFC toolbar only, not for menu bar. Next level of menu are probably top level window and should be seen as popup menu: app.PopupMenu.Menu().

Comment: Thanks for the reply Vasily! PopupMenu is not working for me.  when I use Popup menu, I've got the error not found popupmenu.  'pywinauto.findbestmatch.MatchError: Could not find 'PopupMenu' in 'dict_keys....'

Comment: '<common_controls.ToolbarWrapper - 'Menu Bar', Toolbar, 4197518>' it's my toolbar and I think MenuBarClickInput should support it.  Is that correct?

Comment: Vasily, I really thank you for your help.  I found other menu in toolbar works with MenuBarClickInput method such as menu_bar_click_input('#2->#0->17', app).  Only '#4->#1->#0' submenu is not clickable.  Anyways, thanks again.